# GDB print binary with leading zeros

Tags: c, binary, gdb, embedded

I am trying to print a 32bits register within GDB using the command:

```
define gpioa_moder
    print /t *(uint32_t*)0x48000000
end
```

This is what I get:

> 101000000000000000010010100000

However, I'd like to keep the two leading zeros missing like this:

> **00**101000000000000000010010100000

Thanks

Comment: maybe use the x (examine) cmd rather than print? given an address it will print the address and the value at the address in binary, in this case showing all 32 bits i.e. (gdb)x &my_uint32 -> 0x48000000: 00101000000000000000010010100000, not quite what you want but possibly a bit closer - seems odd there doesn't seem to be a way of specifying the format for the print/t option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try the [`x` (examine) command](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_9.html#SEC56).

Then use it like this:

```
x /w 0x48000000
---> 0x48000000: 00101000000000000000010010100000
```

You can even use the other format parameters `b`, `h` and `g` to print different sizes.

Comment: Alternatively, and with the same effect: `x/4tb 0x48000000 `

Comment: "Examine" is not a replacement for "print". What if I want to print a register?