# gdb print a number as binary with leading zeros (again)

Tags: gdb

Yes, I have seen [GDB print binary with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989720/gdb-print-binary-with-leading-zeros) - but that post seems to deal with printing values of memory locations; instead, I want to print the value `1` as 32-bit binary with leading zeroes in `gdb`.

So this is what I try:

```
$ gdb -q -ex 'p/t 0x0001' -ex 'q'
$1 = 1
```

No leading zeros whatsoever ... and, if I try the answer in the linked question, I get, understandably:

```
$ gdb -q -ex 'x/w 0x0001' -ex 'q'
0x1:    Cannot access memory at address 0x1
```

So, can you print a *value* in `gdb` as binary with a given number of leading zeroes - and if so, how?

EDIT: just found a workaround via [Convert to binary and keep leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926130/convert-to-binary-and-keep-leading-zeros) , given that `python` is embedded in recent `gdb`:

```
$ gdb -q -ex 'py print(format(0x0001, "#034b"))' -ex 'q'
0b00000000000000000000000000000001
```

... but still, is there something like this in the `gdb` built-in language?